# Java SSLPeerUnverifiedException after solve SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

I know is a very common problem, but I describe the context in my case. I write two spring boot 2 application and to both of them I enabled SSL.

Application 1 (Client)

```
server.port: 7070
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key-store-type: PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store: /location/to/keystore/sb1-keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: keystore_password
server.ssl.key-alias: sb1-tomcat

url.user.info: https://localhost:8000/user-info
```

Application 2 (Server)

```
server.port: 8000
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key-store-type: PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store: /location/to/keystore/sb2-keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: keystore_password
server.ssl.key-alias: sb2-tomcat
```

And then I added to my cacerts file the server and also the certificate generated previously with the keytool.

```
keytool -importcert -file "/location/to/certificate/sb2-certificate.crt" -alias sb2-tomcat -keystore "..\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Before add the certificate to the cacerts I got the error SSLHandshakeException, and then a SSLPeerUnverifiedException:

`Certificate for <localhost> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []`

I added the VM Debug-SSL verification to application:

```
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=sb2 localhost, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19498524521301636375327327139235173526668786372574406255907014987664589119007638945302942180083083468997649347515867541667611070267889924617455941875034864650882365195859818334626078471052990327324008622169936539527600386062109638418865197602800058208022394134272787963653612703516681008660079675388888751349158494609089577725407479205584351969790650358305405827665951625886311271743251834381456253493048705893397141460667986714587381315951028909854600446234964732273252958312484308184937316978935692640456235515324828950495838104784778023273184639045008690240699649911570081674849785949521722117188840210828574141181
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Jul 19 14:33:31 CEST 2018,
           To: Sun Jul 16 14:33:31 CEST 2028]
  Issuer: CN=sb2 localhost, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
  SerialNumber: [    52083aa1]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: EB 73 69 B0 29 5A CA F7   4A 85 F4 64 AD 15 90 B4  .si.)Z..J..d....
0010: 92 88 0E 02                                        ....
]
]
```

I have search all day in google but I don't get what I'm missing. Do I need to add some steps?

also reviewing the cacerts with KeyStore explorer I saw all the entries names have a `[jdk]` but not mine cert sb2-tomcat.

Comment: Your cert has CN (CommonName) `"sb2 localhost"`, but the hostname requested in the URL is `"localhost"` which does not match. Change your cert to have name `"localhost"` -- either in CN, or better in the SubjectAlternativeNames extension aka SAN which Java prefers as the error message indicates. Or change your URL to `'sb2 localhost"` which will be hard because name-resolution usually doesn't allow space. PS: if server doesn't ask for client auth then client keystore isn't needed, so if you want to actually use client keystore set `server.ssl.client-auth`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I changed it and works.